# Is QT the right framework to use for simple 2D game in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a simple "Mario-like" 2D game. Nothing too fancy, just a some kind of plubmer  walking and jumping, some bad guys, user interference, few levels. Is QT the right framework to use? My friend suggested me Irrlicht, but that seems much more for 3D stuff.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that QT is the right tool for 2D game development in C++, but you can try [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Also, for future game development questions, there's a better StackExchange web site where you can probably get better answers: [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Qt can be used to make very complicated animations and graphics scenes (2D and 3D). There are tiny examples included in the SDK that you can use to base your work on, but remember you'll be programming in Qt, instead of something a tad more general like OpenGL.

Comment: You'll be programming in C++, not Qt.  Qt is not a programming language.

Comment: Qt is an extension to C++. `QOBJECT`, `signal`, `slot`, and `connect` are not keywords in C++. `moc` is not in the C++ standard. You *will* be programming in Qt.

Comment: they are not keywords in QT either, they are macros and functions.  Come are colored blue only because that's how the IDE colors them.  QT doesn't have it's own compiler, it compiles on any major compiler.  This is because it is standard c++.

Comment: "moc" stands for meta object compiler. I never saw this mentioned in any c++ standard...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`SDL`](http://www.libsdl.org/).

If you want a more OO API, check out [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/). SFML has more done for you in terms of design (a Sprite class, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a big library which provides a lot of features, you would be wanting to use Qt wholly rather than just for 2D drawing.

If you already know qt and are comfortable with it, then its way to go.

Comment: I do not, that's why I want to pick some really carefully..